# Python program just ends after a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a logging in system with python. To login you must first register. After you have registered it stores it into a text file with the password in base64. Then if you login it asks for username and password which the password gets encoded into base64 and is checked against the text document. But when it searches for the password nothing happens. It just ends the program and goes to the shell. No traceback error or anything. It is as though the rest of the code is invisible.
Code is below:

```
try:
    import linecache
    import base64
    import tkinter
    import time
    choice = ""
    def choose():
        choice = input("Would you liek to register or login: ")
        choice = choice.upper()
        if choice == "REGISTER":
            f = open("h.txt", "a")
            f.write("\n")
            print("Please enetr a username")
            username = input(">>> ")
            print("Please enter a password")
            passw = input(">>> ")
            print("\n"*100)
            passw_conf = input("Please enter your password again\n>>> ")
            print("\n"*100)
            if passw == passw_conf:
                print("Thank you for Registering")
                f.write(username + "\n")
                passw = base64.b64encode(passw.encode('utf-8'))
                passw = str(passw)[2:-1]
                f.write(passw + "\n")
                f.close()
                choose()
            else:
                print("Please choose register again as passwords do not match.")
        elif choice == "LOGIN":
            username = input("Please enter your username\n>>> ")
            passw = input("Please enter your password\n>>> ")

            x = 0
            with open("h.txt") as f:
                    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('h.txt')]
            while lines[x] != username:

                print(lines[x])
                if lines == username:
                    print("Got it ;)")
                elif lines != username:
                    print("Not got it ;(")
            passw = base64.b64encode(passw.encode('utf-8'))
            passw = str(passw)[2:-1]
            if passw == lines:
                print("Logged in successfully")
            elif lines == "":
                print("Username not found!")
    choose()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Restarting....")
    time.sleep(8)
    print("\n"*100)
    choose()
    choose()
```

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint (using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) and stepping through the code to see where the program terminates?

Comment: Shouldn't you add `x += 1` inside the while loop? Also you should test `lines[x] == username`, not `lines`, as that is just a list with all the lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many problems with your code. It works only, if the first username in `h.txt` is the entered one, otherwise you have a infinite loop. Second, `lines` is a list, so never equal to `passwd` or `""`. Therefore nothing is printed.

It should look like this:

```
    username = input("Please enter your username\n>>> ")
    passw = input("Please enter your password\n>>> ")

    with open("h.txt") as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    for line in lines:
        if line == username:
            user_password = next(lines)
            break
    else:
        print("Username not found!")
        return
    passw = base64.b64encode(passw.encode('utf-8'))
    passw = passw[2:-1]
    if passw == user_password:
        print("Logged in successfully")
    else:
        print("Wrong password")
```

Answer (score 1):

Executed once, we expect the first line should be username, this means, the `while` breaks at `x=0` (while-start).
Then the variable `lines` is a list, it does not equals to the password and it is not empty (no prints). Sorry the program does what you wrote!

Other things that I see:

- you are opening the file twice (with-statement + line below)
- The while-loop is not a loop (x+=1)
- if-statement after the while-statement can never be true (`if lines[x] == username` cannot work for `lines[x] != username`)

There is a simple way to debug this: **print!**

- one after each line of code
- showing variables you are using to control the flow (`lines`)